# Typescript Infer types from a tuple in React render props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to infer the types from my `fetchData` array so that the parameters I pass to my `children` would be properly typed.

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface DataSource {
  dataSource: () => Promise<unknown>,
}

interface Data {
  data: unknown,
}

interface Props{
  fetchData: DataSource[],
  children: (...data: any[]) => React.ReactNode;
}

interface State {
  data: Data[];
}
    
const Placeholder : React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState<State>({
    data: [],
  });

  const getAllData = async () => {
    const result = await Promise.all(props.fetchData.map((item) => item.dataSource()));
    return result as Data[];
  };

  const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await getAllData();
      setState({
          data,
        });
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const {
    data
  } = state;

  const { children } = props;

  return (
      {children(...data)}
  );
};
```

In the below example:

```
      // const fetchCategories: () => Promise<Category[]>
      // const fetchRoles: () => Promise<Role[]>


      <PlaceHolder fetchData={[{dataSource: fetchCategories }, {dataSource: fetchRoles}]}>
        {(categories /* right now 'categories' type is 'any' but I want to infer type 
         Category[] from 'fetchCategories'  */,
         roles /* same as categories */) => (
          <CreateCategory categories={categories} roles={roles} />
        )}
      </PlaceHolder>
```

Comment: Maybe `children: ([Category[], Roles[]) => React.ReactNode;`. Also, If I'm not mistaking, `children` should be `ReactNode` but you use it as a regular function.

Comment: @MoshFeu then how will the component stay generic?